# pytest return ModuleNotFoundError when module imported in test file import another module within the same directory of the imported module

Tags: python

I am sorry if the title takes some time to understand. So here is the folder structure:

```
falcon_tut/
    falcon_tut/
        app.py
        images.py
        __init__.py
    tests/
        test_app.py
        __init__.py
```

And some codes

```
####################
# app.py
####################



from images import Resource

images = Resource()

api = application = falcon.API()
api.add_route('/images', images)

# ... few more codes


####################
# test_app.py
####################



import falcon
from falcon import testing
import ujson
import pytest

from falcon_tut.app import api

@pytest.fixture
def client():
    return testing.TestClient(api)


def test_list_images(client):
    doc = {
        'images': [
            {
                'href': '/images/1eaf6ef1-7f2d-4ecc-a8d5-6e8adba7cc0e.png'
            }
        ]
    }

response = client.simulate_get('/images')
result_doc = ujson.loads(response.content)

assert result_doc == doc
assert response.status == falcon.HTTP_OK
```

It works fine when running with `python falcon_tut/app.py` and curl it with response of `200` and payload of the images

Until running `pytest tests/` **from the project root** it output this:

```
ImportError while importing test module ../falcon_tut/tests/test_app.py
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
tests/test_app.py:6: in <module>
    from falcon_tut.app import api
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'falcon_tut'
```

I tried creating `__init__.py` at the project root but it still output the same error above

Python version 3.7.0, with falcon 1.4.1, cpython 0.28.5, pytest 3.7.3, and instead of using gunicorn, I am using bjoern 2.2.2

I am trying out the python falcon framework and encounter the error at the testing part.

**==========UPDATE===========**

The reason why `pytest` could not found the module is because `sys.path` does not have `../falcon_tut/falcon_tut` exists.

When I ran `pytest` and edit those 2 files and printing out `sys.path`, it only has `[../falcon_tut/tests, ../falcon_tut, ..]`. The workaround to this is to append the path to the package to `sys.path`. So here is the edited `app.py`

```
#############
# app.py
#############

import sys

# this line is just example, please rewrite this properly if you wants to use this workaround
# sys_path[1] only applied to my situation, again this is just example to know that it works
# the idea is to make sure the path to your module exists in sys.path
# in this case, I appended ../falcon_tut/falcon_tut to sys.path
# so that now ../falcon_tut/falcon_tut/images.py can be found by pytest
sys.path.insert(0, '{}/falcon_tut'.format(sys_path[1]))

# body codes...
```